# Read Global Application property from WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, global-asax

I'm using in my Global.asax class the object Application to store data.

```
Application.Set("data", "test");
```

Now, in my WCF Service, I want to be abble to read this property. How can I do that?

```
Application["data"];
```

In debug, I can see my global.asax is called (Begin_Request), but in my webservice's method, how can I access to this **Application**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var yourData=HttpContext.Current.Application["data"];
```

bear in mind anyway thay if you will deploy the Service on a Server Farm you could have issues as the Application is inProc and each server will have its own Application variable

Answer (score 4):

in order to get the HttpContext.Current working with wcf you gotta turn on compatibility:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

then you can get access as Massimiliano Peluso suggests:

```
// in the wcf service
var yourData=HttpContext.Current.Application["data"];
```