# Storing application level data in a WCF Service

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I am trying to create my first WCF Service and I am trying to store application data.

I have created my ServiceContracts and DataContracts and the service is working.

I now want to read some configuration data from a database and store this data at application scope so that the data is available to any subsequent requests as long as the service is alive.  That way I don't have to connect to the database each time I process a request.  I don't want to store the data in config files, the data already exists in said DB and I don't want to duplicate it.

I have the following implemented and working.

Note 1: I have removed the database code to keep the sample simple.

Note 2: The MemoryCache class exists within the System.Runtime.Caching namespace.

```
private void LoadConfigData()
{
    if (!MemoryCache.Default.Contains("ConfigData"))
    {
        CacheItemPolicy cachePolicy = new CacheItemPolicy() {
                  AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(5) };

        MemoryCache.Default.Add(
                  "ConfigData",
                  "ImagineThereIsDBDataHere",
                  cachePolicy);
    }
}
```

Is this the right approach to use?

This post mentions using the Application class and HttpContext:

[Read Global Application property from WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296981/read-global-application-property-from-wcf-service)

But I have neither of these available in my project currently.

Is this thread safe, will I get race conditions if multiple requests are made to my service and the cache is empty?

This is also my first question so if I have missed any detail let me know and i will update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `MemoryCache` object's [AddOrGetExisting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780583.aspx) method (or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988741.aspx) override) to accomplish this in a thread-safe manner.

Don't worry about the Application or HttpContext classes.  They are in the System.Web namespace and their use in WCF is not advisable.  You're doing the right thing already.